# Add pacer to the nav host in Scaffold- Compose - Transparent bottom bar

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to apply my own bottom bar which has a transparent background, but it is needed to add a Spacer (not padding) with the height of the bottom bar (56.dp) on the bottom side of all screens. However, when I add the spacer in scaffold seems like the spacer is not applying.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navHostController = navHostController) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navHostController)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp).align(Alignment.BottomCenter))
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Box` which overlays their children. The NavHost is going to overlap with the spacer, not sit above it. If you want to have the NavHost above the spacer, use a Column with weights,

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navHostController = navHostController) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navHostController, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp)
        }
    }
}
```

However, you should instead use the padding you are provided by the scaffold, which accounts for the bottom bar:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navHostController = navHostController) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        SetupNavGraph(navController = navHostController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried both ways but none of them solve my problem, I want the content to be visible (for example while I'm scrolling a list) behind the bottom bar, but all these solutions just set a padding under the nav host and the content is not visible behind the bottom bar